# Pitch Shift in p5.js

Tags: p5.js

I've been racking my brain on how to do a pitch shift in p5.js, and I've found documentation for a rate change (pitch and speed together), as well as a speed change without changing pitch.  I was trying to experiment with having those run simultaneously, but it appears rate() is only available for p5.SoundFile and speed is only available for p5.MediaElement.

I was wondering if anyone had run across a way to extend functionality from one object to another, or if there was a way to manually extend the functionality somewhere in custom code.

Answer (score 1):

#### Option 1. Switch to ToneJS

ToneJS is another library that wraps the browser's Audio API and it has a built in [PitchShift](https://tonejs.github.io/docs/r13/PitchShift) effect. There's nothing special about `p5.sound` that makes it better or worse for use with `p5.js` except maybe that it follows some of the same conventions.

#### Option 2. Write a Custom Effect

p5.Sound provides a base class [p5.Effect](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Effect) which could be used to implement a pitch shift effect however, this would be a pretty challenging project unless you have experience with digital signal processing and the underlying browser [Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API). Here's a [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_time_stretching_and_pitch_scaling#Frequency_domain) on the algorithm in question.